# TRANSIENT_FAILURE occurs when a transaction is sent using Gateway that is configured using `WithSDK` in fabric-go-sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I'm building a client server to connect with Hyperledger Fabric network using `fabric-go-sdk`. To use a custom logging system, I get an `FabricSDK` object using `fabsdk.New()` then inject it to a `Gateway` object using `gateway.WithSDK` function. Check the code below:

```golang
    ccpPath := getPath("connection-profile.json", staticPath)
    sdk, err := fabsdk.New(config.FromFile(ccpPath),
        fabsdk.WithLoggerPkg(&FabSDKLoggerProvider{}), // using my custom logging system
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to create a new fabsdk")
    }

    gw, err := gateway.Connect(
        gateway.WithSDK(sdk),
        gateway.WithIdentity(wallet, "admin"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to connect the network via a fabric gateway")
    }
```

When I run a test, I get an error:

```
Failed to submit: error registering for TxStatus event: could not create client conn: could not connect to peer0.test.bpl:7051: dialing connection on target [peer0.test.bpl:7051]: connection is in TRANSIENT_FAILURE
```

The test that I ran is a test to send a transaction using the `Gateway` object and its `Submit` method.

When I defined a `Gateway` object without `FabricSDK`, it works fine. That is, if I use the code below, the test passes well. However, in this case, I cannot use my custom logging system. (I just want to disable Fabric SDK's logging system.)

```golang
    ccpPath := getPath("connection-profile.json", staticPath)
    gw, err := gateway.Connect(
        gateway.WithConfig(config.FromFile(ccpPath)),
        gateway.WithIdentity(wallet, "admin"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to connect the network via a fabric gateway")
    }
```

According to my investigation, difference between `FabricSDK` objects initialized by `fabsdk.New()` and `gateway.Connect(gateway.WithConfig())` is that the `FabricSDK` object that is created by `gateway.Connect(gateway.WithConfig())` has the option `fabsdk.WithMSPPkg(gw.mspfactory)` but the other does not. I try to give the same option to my `fabsdk.New()` code, I could not find how to do it.

So, my question is:

- How can I deal with "TRANSIENT_FAILURE" error, or
- How can I disable the Fabric SDK's default logging system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had exactly the same two questions while writing a little sample CLI to get chaincode metadata

> How can I deal with "TRANSIENT_FAILURE" error

In my case, the `dialing connection on target [peer0.org1.example.com:7051]: connection is in TRANSIENT_FAILURE` error was because I was using the Fabric test network docker environment but I had not set the DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST environment variable. DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST determines whether IP addresses found during service discovery are translated from the docker network to the local host, which is described in the [Connection Options](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/developapps/connectionoptions.html) documentation for developing applications.

> How can I disable the Fabric SDK's default logging system?

I still wanted to see error messages but I was able to change the logging level to get rid of unwanted info messages using `logging.SetLevel("", logging.ERROR)`

The [ccmetadata sample is on GitHub if that's any help](https://github.com/hyperledgendary/ccmetadata)